# I'm getting into blender. I have some quick questions

Tags: blur, photorealism

So I'm thinking about getting into blender, especially since the new release that makes things easier for newcomers just came out. Now I just saw the video "The Secret Ingredient to Photorealism" and I have a few questions about photorealism in blender before I get into it.

1. Does blender use bokeh, lens blur or some equivalent. (because I just saw computerphile's video on the topic and wanted to know how it's blurring works)
2. Does it apply effects before or after square rooting (because if it does it after it'll make it go from green to brown to red when blurring instead of green to yellow to red)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, Blender has bokeh blur in compositing nodes. As to the second question go to https://www.blendernetwork.org/contact to ask the devs. And next time make it **one** question at a time - you may gain more rep if your separate questions score.

Comment: Related: [How to create Bokeh circles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32861/how-to-create-bokeh-circles/32863#32863)